# IntelliJ: How to use external JAR's as a library, when the JAR's have no packages

Tags: java, maven, grails, intellij-idea, dependency-management

This question is related to setting up an IntelliJ environment for Princeton's Algorithms 2 course available on Coursera.

I am trying to import external libraries, as JARs, into my project. I was able to add the JARs from the Project Structure menu via `Project Structure` -> `Libraries` -> `New Project Library (the green plus sign)`. Now I have a class under `src`, `WordNet.java`, but I can only access my external libraries using the default package (ie no package). I would like to create packages to organize my code, but how can I import the external libraries from inside a package? Is there a simple solution to directly import the JAR's, or perhaps I can use Maven or Grails? Providing a simple answer for all of my options would be great.

I have the following project structure, with a `src` directory, `src/assignemnt1` package, and `External Libraries/stdlib/stdlib.jar` external library:

[image: intelliJ project]

My class that uses the external libraries, `WordNet.java`, has code as follows:

```
public class WordNet {

    // constructor takes the name of the two input files
    public WordNet(String synsets, String hypernyms) {
        In read_synsets = new In(synsets);
        read_synsets.hasNextLine();

    }
}
```

Where `In` is a class under `stdlib.jar`. Under the default package, I can use `In` without importing. Unfortunately, if I have `WordNet.java` under `src/assignment1` (inside the `assignment1` package), I cannot seem to import `In` and IntelliJ offers no import suggestions either. Is there a way to use `stdlib.jar` within `WordNet.java`, inside the `src/assignment1` package? Or do I have to stay withing the default package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) forbids any imports from the unnamed, or default, package.

> A type in an unnamed package (§7.4.2) has no canonical name, so the requirement for a canonical name in every kind of import declaration implies that (a) types in an unnamed package cannot be imported, and (b) static members of types in an unnamed package cannot be imported. As such, §7.5.1, §7.5.2, §7.5.3, and §7.5.4 all require a compile-time error on any attempt to import a type (or static member thereof) in an unnamed package.

In order to access these classes from outside the default package without modifying the library, you would need to use reflection.

Additionally, the reason you don't need an import when your class is in the default package, is because you don't need to import classes when they are in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is impossible. Specifically, you cannot "import" the default package into a named package. Since the library you're using has its classes in the default package, your only recourse is to use the default package as well, if you want to use the library.

Of course, you could move the library's classes to a package, but that's a different story.

Comment: If I move the library's classes to a package, would that involve changing the JAR's themselves? I do not want to alter the JAR's. Perhaps I can use Maven to import 3rd party jars?

Comment: Importing means different things for different constructs. Importing a JAR (through maven or any other means) means you're making all the classes in that JAR available to the class loader.
Importing a class (with the `import` keyword) means that whatever you are importing becomes available to that class.

Thus, importing the JAR won't help, since the package of the classes within is still only the default package.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why do I not need to "import" classes from a JAR's default package when my class is also in the default package? Are classes that share the default package considered to be in the same "space" across the whole project, regardless of whether they are inside or outside of a JAR? From your explanation, it seems that a default package is a "special space" that cannot be referenced anywhere outside of the default package, correct?

Comment: Yes, and no. The way it works is that any class defined in package A, can "see" any other class in that package (with some restrictions - see scoping rules). The default package is a special case in that you cannot opt into seeing the classes in it, where you can do that for any other package using an import statement.